# Dropbox always asking permission (OAuth)

Tags: c#, oauth, dropbox, dropbox-api

I'm implementing Dropbox access into my .NET application

I have a question about the token system by OAuth 2 from Dropbox.

The steps I followed to successfully getting data from Dropbox
ClientSecret and ClientId are given ofc

**1.** Authorize: by calling https://www.dropbox.com/1/oauth2/authorize

**2.** Verify the code by `Request.QueryString("code")`

**3.** Getting Account info with the response see below:

**Getting Account info**

```
var client = new HttpClient()
{
    BaseAddress = new Uri("https://api.dropbox.com")
};

client.DefaultRequestHeaders.Authorization = new AuthenticationHeaderValue("Bearer", token);
var response = await client.GetAsync("/1/account/info");
var AccountData = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<DropBoxAccountData>(await response.Content.ReadAsStringAsync());

//Note: DropBoxAccountData is my custom class.
// The Token is also given don't show the code just the querystring["code"]   
// that dropbox return by youre redirect_uri
```

Everything works fine so far.
The first step every time a user access my webpage it needs to be verified by his/her Dropbox account to allow permission from my Dropbox app.

The second time it needs to be know by the application using MSSQL Database or just session for example.

But it looks like it always expires?

Please is there someone that can point me into the right direction.

Answer (score 0):

Once you have the access token ("`token`" in your code above), you just need to save it. It sounds like you're building a web app, so yes, you would typically store this in the user's session or perhaps associated with the user in a database, if you have such a thing.

Comment: What to do after saving it Re-Authenticate

Comment: I dont get it everytime i need to renew the code else i don't have access

Comment: In the code you shared, you have an access token. Just save it and use it again next time. I don't know what "renew the code" means to you. Access tokens don't expire.